# VKSdk android java изображение в альбом (vk api)

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь загрузить изображение в свой альбом вк. Использую [этот код](http://pastebin.com/3CSQvC50), уже долго не могу разобраться, поэтому пробую разные способы. В каждом из них мне удается пройти авторизацию, а затем:
в первом способе ничего не происходит,
во втором выпадает `exception` указанный ниже и приложение закрывается, в третьем аналогично второму. Как исправить ошибку?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=10485, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.molodec.vktest/com.example.molodec.vktest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference


File photo = new File("android.jpg"); Первый способ
final Bitmap photo = getPhoto(); Второй способ
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open("android.jpg")); Третий способ
```

Comment: Возможно, у вас нет в манифесте разрешения на чтение файлов. Возможно оно есть, но тестируете на 6 андроиде и там не запрашиваете разрешение во время исполнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод грузит картинку для постинга на стену. После его выполнения необходимо выполнять wall.post с нужными параметрами. Изучи тщательно этот код:

```
final Bitmap photo = getPhoto();
                VKRequest request = VKApi.uploadWallPhotoRequest(new VKUploadImage(photo, VKImageParameters.jpgImage(0.9f)), 0, TARGET_GROUP);
                request.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        recycleBitmap(photo);
                        VKApiPhoto photoModel = ((VKPhotoArray) response.parsedModel).get(0);
                        makePost(new VKAttachments(photoModel));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(VKError error) {
                        showError(error);
                    }
                });

private void makePost(VKAttachments attachments) {
        makePost(attachments, null);
    }
private void makePost(VKAttachments attachments, String message) {
        VKRequest post = VKApi.wall().post(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, "-" + TARGET_GROUP, VKApiConst.ATTACHMENTS, attachments, VKApiConst.MESSAGE, message));
        post.setModelClass(VKWallPostResult.class);
        post.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                if (isAdded()) {
                    VKWallPostResult result = (VKWallPostResult) response.parsedModel;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format("https://vk.com/wall-%d_%s", TARGET_GROUP, result.post_id)));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                showError(error.apiError != null ? error.apiError : error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Скопировал getPhoto() из исходников тестого приложения vkandroidsk и не получилось импортировать зависимость Activity в методе. Кроме того не понял где взять зависимость для recyleBitmap, а isAdded вообще не нашел

Comment: @bolshoymolodec Если у вас проблема именно с перекодированием, то попробуйте этот фрагмент кода: Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.post); В bitmap будет изображение, перекодированное из post.png, которое лежит у вас в drawable

Comment: @bolshoymolodec а также почитайте здесь инфу: https://new.vk.com/dev/upload_files